# Remove arrow mark from shortcut icons on Windows 8

Tags: windows-registry, icons, windows-8

I tried this registry tweak to remove the shortcut arrows, which worked on Windows 7, but doesn't work on Windows 8 anymore. It just shows a white space instead of an arrow.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile]
"IsShortcut"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut]
"IsShortcut"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\piffile]
"IsShortcut"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WSHFile]
"IsShortcut"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons]
"29"=-
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an empty icon. Download it from [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ScriptsGuy/noArrows.zip), then extract it to some folder (for example **C:\Icons**). Next save the text below as **NoShortcutArrow.reg** (name doesn't matter as long as the extension is **.REG**, but make sure to edit the text first if you have changed the path to the icon), then double-click it and merge the contents with the registry.

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell
>   Icons] "29"="C:\\Icons\\noarrow.ico"

Answer (score 1):

The following reg tweak deletes the arrow from the shortcut icons

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile] "IsShortcut"=-
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut] "IsShortcut"=-
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\piffile] "IsShortcut"=-
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WSHFile] "IsShortcut"=-
```

The following reg tweak reinserts a renamed icon  arrow short (results = no arrows)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile] "NoIsShortcut"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut] "NoIsShortcut"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\piffile] "NoIsShortcut"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WSHFile] "NoIsShortcut"=""
```

I tried the method of using a blank icon such as noArrow.ico as outlined on [this page](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-remove-shortcut-arrow.htm), and this simply did not work for me.