# Is it possible to remove the shortcut overlay from an icon on the desktop in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove arrow mark from shortcut icons on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/482797/remove-arrow-mark-from-shortcut-icons-on-windows-8)

I'd like to remove the little shortcut symbol from the Chrome icon. Is this possible in Windows 8?

[image]

Comment: Do you want it only for Chrome or for other apps as well?

Answer (score 3):

Taken from this guide: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-remove-shortcut-arrow.htm

1. Download the [no arrow icon](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ScriptsGuy/noArrows.zip) and extract it, preferably where it won't bother you
2. Launch regedit (windows key + r, type regedit and hit enter)
3. Navigate to this path: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
4. Create a new key called Shell Icons
5. In Shell Icons, right-click and create a new REG_SZ called 29. ([as such](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/images/win8/shell_icons.jpg))
6. Set the newly created entry to the path to your .ico file that you extracted in step 1
7. Log out/in, done

Comment: Could you please summarize the most important parts of the link here, on-site? Link-only answers aren't considered real answers.

Comment: Edited my response!

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend a [3rd party tool](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/38708-Windows-Shortcut-Arrow-Editor-Remove-shortcut-arrow-Windows-8-7-amp-Vista-%28or-change%29) avoid any messy registry editing.

[image]